# Scrolling on mobile accordion menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress-theming

I made this website with an accordion menu in a sidebar on mobile, and there is one little problem i can not solve.

If you look at the page https://lieth-schule.de and open the sidebar on a mobile device (button underneath the image banner) you can see the accordion menu. If you now open a submenu, you can only scroll if you exactly hit the scrollbar of the whole sidebar.

What do I have to change in order to be able to scroll the entire sidebar, when touching and holding anywhere inside it? Like you would do on a mobile touch device?

Comment: Whatever library you're using adds an event listener to both `click` and `touchstart` events and prevents the defaults. `$(this.element).children("ul").find("li").bind("click touchstart", function(e) {...}` preventing default on `touchstart` means no scrolling. It's not needed anyways, the click handler is more than enough, even on mobile.

Comment: @jayrrr hey from which domain have you uploaded this website!!

Comment: @Aahad what do you mean?

Comment: I meant to say how did you upload this site on the web  !! @jayrrr

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the scroll does not work because the opening of accordions is done through `mousedown`
Need to be converted to `click`